# INSERT/SELECT slow after TRUNCATE TABLE on table with 6 over mllion rows

Tags: sql-server, truncate

Seeing slowness in insert/select after truncating a table that has over 6 million rows.

I daily insert 5 to 6 millions records into a table and I was able to insert/select data without any issue for some 7 or 8 days but when the table size went above 10 GB / 30 million rows, there were a few timeout issues.

So I thought of truncating the table daily before data uploading since 1 day's data is enough for me. Now I am seeing extreme slowness after truncating. I am using sql server 2008.

do i need to update table stats? or is it some thing related to ghost rows?

Comment: You should look at lock escalations and blocking if any. Also updating stats would be very good idea since your scenario has huge data change

Comment: thx shanky , there is no locking / blocking , since only one process uploads also no process is reading data till upload finishes. when i was uploading data with out truncate the process(calculation/upload) would complete in 1hours , now after truncate today it took 6 or 7 hours.

Comment: When the query is running slow, run sp_WhoIsActive and see what the wait types are for the query. http://www.brentozar.com/go/active

Comment: As others pointed out, truncating basically leaves all statistics and indexes all outdated and fragmented. Also, if your table is basically a dump table for data, you might want to alter it as a heap instead of clustered (which I assume it is). Heaps are ideal for pretty much nothing, *except* for huge bulk inserts. Either way, to read data from there you'll need to update the statistics for the query planner to have any clue what the data looks like and how it's ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update statistics` *tablename*.  Enjoy.

Comment: After enabling auto stats update , every thing went normal. from now After truncating big tables i will makes sure table stats get updated if DB auto stats update is disabled.. thanks every one for all your valuable suggestions.